# Release preview: Can not find a resource with the Name/Key FocusVisualWhiteStrokeBrush

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I use FocusVisualWhiteStrokeBrush brush in my application.

This resource is existed in **consumer preview** of Windows 8.
This is brush is used for defining template of xaml button in consumer preview of Windows 8.

But in **release preview** I have gotten exception with "Can not find a resource with the Name/Key FocusVisualWhiteStrokeBrush" message.

Maybe someone know how can I use resource with FocusVisualWhiteStrokeBrush brush in my application?

I am using Express 2012 RC for Windows 8 visual studio.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

To add to this - for future reference, if anyone has similar errors for other resources, please see: http://aka.ms/rpdevdoc (Goes to download.microsoft.com).

This document has a table of old -> new resource names to help migrate apps from consumer preview to the new release preview templates.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer using :Blend for Visual Studio" :) - FocusVisualWhiteStrokeBrush is renamed to FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush